# Equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry

A curve is convex in the plane if it is true that any straight line between two points $P$, $Q$ of the curve, the segment $\overline{PQ}$ appears inside the curve. Suppose $C$ is a convex curve in the plane. Show geometrically that there exists an equilateral triangle whose vertices are at $C$.